# VMWare Workstation: how to show removable device icon on top bar like VMWare Player?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I was using VMWare player on windows10 and installed a Ubuntu guest, and it works fine.

Now I purchased the workstation pro but I found that all the removable device icons can only be displayed on the bottom status bar. They are not visible in full-screen mode. In full-screen mode I must go to the TopBar->VM->RemovableDeviecs->SomeDevice to change the connection state, which is very inconvenient.

Does anyone know how to show the icons of removable devices on the top bar of VMWareWorkstation?

Comment: I don't think that there is any way to enable it in VMware Workstation (Pro). (Searching for strings through the various `.dll` and `.exe` files for "pref", there is a `pref.vmplayer.deviceBarToplevel` preference, but that's Player-specific, and there does not appear to be a corresponding one for VMware Workstation.)

Comment: And IIRC the motivation for the feature in VMware Player (which lacks a status bar) didn't exist in VMware Workstation, which is why it was never added.  Additionally Workstation has a lot more existing toolbar buttons, so there was reluctance to add a potentially long list of additional buttons.

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for your comment. Yes you are right, the top bar of worksataion has 40% of the blank area, which is used to display removable devices on player.

Comment: I am wondering, if possible, is there a way to show status bar in fullscreen mode when the pointer moves to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: No, there unfortunately is no way to enable that either.  You will need to get used to doing Ctrl+Alt, Alt+M, D, first letter of your desired device, C (to connect) or D (to Disconnect).  Or close the VM and reopen it in VMware Player.

Comment: Unfortunately, VMWare player was automatically uninstalled when I installed the workstation. And I cannot install it again unless I uninstall the purchased workstation.

Comment: No, VMware Workstation Pro *includes* a copy of VMware Player.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of it.